# rails partial not processing locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

The following view is calling a partial and declaring locals for it in a way that is [consistent with the Rails guides](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html):

```
<% @wines_for_winetype.each_with_index do |wine, index| %>
  <%= render 'price_table', locals: {wine: wine} %>
```

But this is generating an error

> undefined local variable or method 'wine' for #<#:0x00007fba1fb97298>  Did you mean?  @wine @wines

Yet in the dev mode with the live shell the following:
[image]
demonstrates that the locals exist.

Why are they not being handled in the view partial according to expected syntax?  how should this me fixed?

Comment: By the way, you may want to look into **collection rendering**. It could be significantly more performant than your current code (and would require minimal change)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the `partial` keyword:

```
<% @wines_for_winetype.each_with_index do |wine, index| %>
  <%= render partial: 'price_table', locals: {wine: wine} %>
```

Answer (score 2):

@mrzasa is right. If you want to omit the `partial` keyword, then you need to omit the `locals` keyword too.

```
<%= render 'price_table', wine: wine %>
```

Comment: Useful answer; the multiple possible syntassi can be slippery.